How can I have ScrollTargetBehaviour change based off scroll position?
I'm working on an app where I have one or more featured, full screen views presented before the rest of the "explore" content (think home page on Spotify).
I have the following structure at the moment:
GeometryReader { proxy in
        let h = proxy.size.height
        
        ScrollView {
          if data == nil {
            Recommended(event: nil)
              .padding(.vertical, 8)
              .frame(height: h)
              .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
          } else {
            LazyVStack(spacing: proxy.safeAreaInsets.bottom / 2) {
              ForEach(data?.recommended ?? []) { _ in
                Recommended(event: events[0])
                  .padding(.vertical, 8)
                  .frame(height: h)
                  .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                  .padding(.bottom, proxy.safeAreaInsets.bottom / 2)
              }
            }
            .scrollTargetLayout()
          }
          
          if let sections = data?.sections {
            LazyVStack(spacing: 32) {
              ForEach(Array(sections.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { e in
                let section = e.element
                  
                EventRow(title: section.title, events: section.events)
              }
            }
            .scrollTargetLayout()
          }
          
          Spacer()
        }
    //    .scrollPosition(id: $scrollID) this was an attempt
    //    .scrollTargetBehavior(.custom) this was another attempt
        .scrollDisabled(data == nil)
        .scrollIndicators(.hidden)
        .ignoresSafeArea(.container)
        .refreshable {
          print("refresh")
        }
        .onChange(of: scrollID) { _, newValue in
          print(newValue ?? "")
        }
      }

I attempted to switch the paging style based off the scrollID but got the following after writing a ternary
.scrollTargetBehavior(true ? .paging : .viewAligned)

// Member 'viewAligned' in 'PagingScrollTargetBehavior' produces result of type 'ViewAlignedScrollTargetBehavior', but context expects 'PagingScrollTargetBehavior'

I was also looking into a custom implementation of scroll target behavior but my experimentation yielded few results.
Minimal Reproducible Example
struct ContentView: View {
  let colors: [Color] = [.blue, .green, .yellow, .red]

  var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { proxy in
      ScrollView(.vertical) {
        LazyVStack(spacing: proxy.safeAreaInsets.bottom / 2) {
          ForEach(0 ..< 2) { i in
            ZStack {
              Rectangle()
                .fill(colors[i % colors.count].opacity(0.6))
                .containerRelativeFrame([.horizontal, .vertical])
                .padding(.bottom, proxy.safeAreaInsets.bottom / 2)
                .frame(
                  width: proxy.size.width,
                  height: proxy.size.height + (proxy.safeAreaInsets.bottom / 2)
                )
              Text("Video \(i + 1)")
                .font(.title)
                .bold()
            }
          }
        }
        .scrollTargetLayout()
        
        // these elements should scroll normally without snapping
        ForEach(0 ..< 20) { i in
          Rectangle()
            .fill(.purple)
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            .overlay {
              Text("\(i)")
            }
        }
      }
      .scrollTargetBehavior(.paging)
      .ignoresSafeArea(edges: .bottom)
    }
  }
}

#Preview {
  ContentView()
}


What is wrong with your current code exactly? From your description .viewAligned is what you want. Why do you want the scroll target behaviour to change, at all?

@Sweeper It's totally possible I'm misunderstanding something but I can't seem to perfectly align my scrolling with the Recommended views viewAligned (it'll settle on the text in the view or something like that). Going for something like TikTok's scroll here which works well with .paging
The ideal would be .paging behavior for the Recommenders and the default scroll behavior for the sections. (Not sure if it's possible to specify the default scroll behavior to .scrollTargetBehavior)

Was playing around with two ScrollView's but couldn't get the two to cooperate with each other

Instead of Recommended and EventRow, can you show a [mcve] that I can copy and paste into a new project and reproduce the issue?

Yessir will get on that

@Sweeper Please lmk if this is adequate and appreciate your patience

You can write your own ScrollTargetBehaviour. Its updateTarget will check where the scroll view would naturally scroll to, and if it is still in the "paging area", delegate to PagingScrollTargetBehavior. Otherwise it would do nothing, i.e. scroll naturally.
struct PartlyPagingBehaviour: ScrollTargetBehavior {
    let pageCount: Int
    func updateTarget(_ target: inout ScrollTarget, context: TargetContext) {
        let targetDimension = context.axes == .vertical ? target.rect.maxY : target.rect.maxX
        let containerDimension = context.axes == .vertical ? context.containerSize.height : context.containerSize.width
        if targetDimension < containerDimension * CGFloat(pageCount) {
            PagingScrollTargetBehavior.paging.updateTarget(&target, context: context)
        }
    }
}

This implementation uses the natural behaviour if any part of the non-paging area is visible, by checking target.rect.maxY. You can check target.rect.minY instead, if you want the paging area to be entirely invisible before the natural behaviour starts.
For the example in the MRE, you can use
.scrollTargetBehavior(PartlyPagingBehaviour(pageCount: 2))

That said, the snapping to each page is a bit slower than the actual .paging behaviour. I assume PagingScrollTargetBehavior is a special case that SwiftUI checks for, and handles it a bit differently.
